# Not working Process-pool after adding shared memory component with mutex lock

Tags: c, webserver, mutex, shared-memory

I am programming a small web server in C that is supposed to serve multiple client requests using a process pool. The process pool was working fine, before adding a shared memory component to store the number of traffic sent by the server. All requests were handled by different processes before. Now they are all handled by the same process. I haven't changed the code to fork() the child-processes, which is what baffles me..

```
typedef struct {
    long int traffic;
    pthread_mutex_t muxlock;
} shmem;

/*Creating the shared memory and,setting its size, closing | Initializing the mutex*/
  shm_unlink("/sum_traffic");
  int shmfd = shm_open("/sum_traffic", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR); //Creates the shared memory
  ftruncate(shmfd,sizeof(int)*8+sizeof(shmem)); //Sets the size of the shared memory
  shmem *memptr = mmap(NULL, (sizeof(int)*8+sizeof(shmem)), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shmfd,0); //Maps a pointer for us to work with
  pthread_mutex_init(&(*memval).muxlock,NULL); //Initialize the mutex lock

//Forking 10 worker processes
int i;
for(i=0; i<11;i++){
  if(pid>0){
      pid=fork();
  }
}

if(pid < 0){
    fprintf(stderr, "Error forking, error: %d\n",errno);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//Worker-processes 
while(1)
  if(pid == 0){
     //Accept connection on list_s
     if((conn_s = accept(list_s, NULL, NULL)) < 0){
          fprintf(stderr , "Error calling accept \n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    httpRequest request;
    request = parseRequest(getMessage(conn_s)); //Parses the http GET request
    headertraffic=selectHeader(conn_s,request.returncode); //Selects a Header file to send
    currenttraffic=printFile(conn_s,request.filename); //Serves the requested file
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(*memval).muxlock); //Lock the mutex to write to shared memory
    (*memval).traffic=((*memval).traffic+currentdata+headerdata);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(*memval).muxlock); // Unlock mutex
        printf("PID: %d\n",getpid());
    (void)close(conn_s);
  }
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Ok so what is the question? What is wrong after adding the shared memory?

Comment: The task is executed by the same process all the time. Before it was different processes serving the requests

Comment: Immediately after you call `fork()`, check the return code.  0 => code is running in parent (continue loop), -1 => error (error handler), or N => code is running in child (break out of loop).  What value does `pid` have before `if (pid > 0)` is executed?

Comment: Hmm I don't exactly understand your question? I initialize `pid_t pid;` Then I assumed the the the kernel will execute `if (pid > 0)` only if I'm in the parent process. Is this assumption wrong?

Comment: `pid = fork()` will create a child process that will return from this function call with a `pid > 0` but it is still in the for loop. The parent process will return from this function call with a `pid = 0` still in the for loop but it will not create any more children.

Comment: What does `top -H <pid>` show you?  How many threads do you create?  I think more than you expect.  FYI "for (i=0;**i<11**;i++)" will create 11 threads (0-10 => 11).

Comment: @Jamie Royer - No, the reverse.  Children will be 0.

Comment: Oh I see you in reality my parent process only creates 1 child, and the other children are created in that sequence child--> creating child? How would I go about creating a pool of 10 child processes from 1 parent then?

Comment: Thank @duck - I just realized that.  @Abhischek, I made a mistake. But the child process will still complete the loop before carrying on.  Also the parent process will enter an infinite loop (100% CPU usage) after creating the child processes maybe add an else with a sleep() if you really don't want the parent doing anything.  Maybe the load is low that one thread is able to handle the traffic.  Add a sleep after `close(conn_s)` to give yourself time to test that theory.

Comment: Thanks @JamieRoyer. I should be able to prevent my parent from infinite loop by moving `if(pid==0)` above the `while(1)`shouldn't I?I execute port binding before I fork, which I meant to be done by the parent. So once I fork, I don't want my parent to do anything else. After adding `sleep(1)` the server crashes, so I am really not creating the child processes as mentioned earlier. This is very mysterious to me because my code was working before adding the shared memory component :(

Comment: strictly speaking, a mutex that is shared between several processes needs to be pthread_mutex_init-ialized with an attribue of `pshared` (see pthread_mutexattr_setpshared and pthread_mutexattr_init)

Comment: OH I've just realized that by I mistyped my declaration of pid `pid_t pid =1;` when I added the shared memory component. D'OH. :( Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is your real code but some error checking would be helpful.

This may not be your problem but a contributing factor is that you haven't set the mutex to be shared by multiple processes.  You can't take the default attributes in `pthread_mutex_init()`.  You have to initialize a mutex attribute with   pthread_mutexattr_init()`and then call`pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()`and then call`pthread_mutex_init()`.

Comment: Hmm interestingly my code still creates 10 processes, when I set `pid_t pid = 1;` before forking. Without using `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()` to initialize the mutex. `ps -all` returns 10 processes now :) And my program output now returns different PIDs for the requests. Still `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared()` is an interesting issue. I will definitely investigate this. Thank you